# Timezone conversion and date formatting in jasper reports?

Tags: java, timezone, jasper-reports, simpledateformat, date-conversion

I am working with a Jasper report where I want to show selected date range along with time. I have used following expression to format the date but it shows time in GMT time zone.

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").format($P{START_DATE})+" "+new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format($P{startTime})
```

The above code gives date as 01-Mar-2019 14:30 which should be 01-Mar-2019 8:00PM as per IST.

How can I handle timezone to show correct time?

Comment: Have you tried setting the timezone?

Comment: Yes I tried but not able to write it in a single statement. I tried following approaches.                                                                                                        
new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").setTimeZone('IST').format($P{startTime}) - This gives error as format() cannot be applied on a void type as setTimeZone() returns void.

Comment: Is the requirement to write it in a single statement?

Comment: Yes. We cannot write multiline expression/java code(One line will be object creation, calling setTimezone() on this object and then call format() to format my input date) in jasper.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead use `DateTimeFormatter` and other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 7):

Probably you should just set TimeZone to your environment and in general you should [avoid using](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1969442/5292302) the old `java.util.Date` class.

If you are running on java 8 or above, you can use similar code to display the time in desired time zone.

```
<textField>
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="ac702c94-69e5-4439-9d32-3c944119dbe6"/>
    <textFieldExpression>
       <![CDATA[java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm").
     withZone(java.time.ZoneId.of("Asia/Calcutta")).format($P{START_DATE}.toInstant())]]>
   </textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

If you are not on java 8 you can use libraries like [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) or [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) to have this functionality.

## Full example with different zoneId on same java.util.Date

**jrxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="TimeZone" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="b3143043-a16b-43db-81c4-6313b0d4922c">
    <parameter name="START_DATE" class="java.util.Date">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <title>
        <band height="60" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="150" height="20" uuid="a0353412-1861-4c12-ac26-b40a6768a88c"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[America/New_York]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="150" y="0" width="150" height="20" uuid="28b938b9-d117-4447-91d2-b5bb9334bad6"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Europe/Rome]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="300" y="0" width="150" height="20" uuid="adceb53f-555d-4be3-bd1e-c9d55b90d90d"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Asia/Calcutta]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="150" height="20" uuid="ebf48192-f394-447b-8264-e66c56289f54"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm").withZone(java.time.ZoneId.of("America/New_York")).format($P{START_DATE}.toInstant())]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="150" y="20" width="150" height="20" uuid="ebf48192-f394-447b-8264-e66c56289f54"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm").withZone(java.time.ZoneId.of("Europe/Rome")).format($P{START_DATE}.toInstant())]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="300" y="20" width="150" height="20" uuid="ac702c94-69e5-4439-9d32-3c944119dbe6"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm").withZone(java.time.ZoneId.of("Asia/Calcutta")).format($P{START_DATE}.toInstant())]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

**Output**

[image: result]

Comment: With this code it still gives me same time in Asia/Calcutta zone.

Comment: @PratikRawlekar I have added a full example that you can test

Answer (score 1):

Use the builtin date formatting function to format values according to the report time zone (the value of the `REPORT_TIME_ZONE` parameter):

```
DATEFORMAT($P{START_DATE}, "dd-MMM-yyyy") + " " + DATEFORMAT($P{startTime}, "HH:mm")
```

Comment: I am getting below error after using it. Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression for source text: ": "+DATEFORMAT($P{START_DATE}, "dd-MMM-yyyy") + " " + DATEFORMAT($P{startTime}, "HH:mm")+" to "+DATEFORMAT($P{END_DATE}, "dd-MMM-yyyy") + " " + DATEFORMAT($P{endTime}, "HH:mm")

Comment: Post the full exception stacktrace (including Caused by.. lines).

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net.sf.jasperreports.functions.standard.DateTimeFunctions
 at details_summary_1551698058964_17203.DATEFORMAT(details_summary_1551698058964_17203:1209)
 at details_summary_1551698058964_17203.evaluate(details_summary_1551698058964_17203:401)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluate(JREvaluator.java:251)
 ... 19 more

Comment: Is there a jasperreports-functions jar on the classpath of the application that runs the report?

Answer (score 0):

To change the date and time displayed in the footer of a Jasper report, you will need to modify the report template. Here are the general steps to follow:

Open the Jasper report in the JasperSoft Studio or other report design tool.

Select the "Page Footer" section of the report template.

In the "Properties" pane, locate the "Date Format" property and modify it according to the format you want to display. For example, you can use the following format to display the date and time in Malawi time zone:

new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz").format(new java.util.Date(),new java.util.Locale("en", "MW"))

Preview the report to confirm that the date and time are now displayed in the correct format.